# Batch file - Discovered program path (variable) - Run program from discovered reg value (path)

Tags: batch-file, registry, steam

I'm trying to create a batch file that will discovered the location of a EXE in this case Steam, and runs that EXE with the discovered path from the registry. The reason I want to discover the install path via the registry is because this batch file is to run over multiple machines and the Steam install paths could be different.

The registry is the constant that holds these paths. Now I believe Steam stores it's install path at:

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam\"
SteamExe = X:\Path\Steam.exe
```

So first I need to know how to grab this value and then I would like to know how to take that value and input it into a run command so Steam runs.

Could you help?

Comment: FYI, steam sets a global environment variable with the `steamapps` path when you install it.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,3" %%E in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam"') do (
    if %%E==SteamExe echo "%%F"
)

pause
```

`reg query` Get all keys and values for the registry path.

`for /f` Visit each line of the queried registry data and split the data so "Name" is stored in 'E' and "Data" is stored in 'F'.
         If 'E' equals "SteamExe" then echo 'F', which will display the steam executable path.

Command-line version:

```
@for /f "tokens=1,3" %E in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam"') do @if %E==SteamExe @echo "%F"
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me? Sorry I'm not great with Batch files at the moment. So this command you've outlined will return the value stored in the registry?

How do I now take that path it returns and change the current director to the one it returned?

Comment: why don't you try and see what it does?

Answer (score 1):

I approached another way, this will work.

```
setlocal

regedit /e reg_exported.tmp "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam"
find "SteamExe" reg_exported.tmp | findstr "SteamExe" >> line_exported.tmp
set /p SteamPath= < line_exported.tmp
set SteamPath=%SteamPath:~11%

del reg_exported.tmp
del line_exported.tmp

start "Steam" %SteamPath%

endlocal
```