# How to find the directory of an executable using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I just want to start of saying that I'm a bit of a noob at batch files. The application steam is a digital distribution platform. I'm trying to make a batch file that'll modify a steam game. I've figure out how to modify the game but the application 'steam' can be installed in any directory on any drive. I know that in task manager you can right click on a process and click open file location and it'll take you to where the application is. I was wondering if anybody knew how to do this in a batch file and then include it in a directory like %filelocation%\content\content

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of the question at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12071458/6738015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable and path should both be found in a specific place in the user registry:

```
@Echo Off
Set "SExe="
Set "SPth="
For /F "Tokens=1,2*" %%A In ('Reg Query HKCU\SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam') Do (
    If "%%A" Equ "SteamExe" Set "SExe=%%C"
    If "%%A" Equ "SteamPath" Set "SPth=%%C")
If Not Defined SExe Exit/B
Rem Your commands go under here for example
Echo=The full path to the Steam executable is "%SExe%"
If Defined SPth Echo=The Steam folder path is "%SPth%"
Timeout -1 1>Nul
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the steam executable is named steam.exe and assuming that executable is in a directory in the system's PATH environment variable then you can get the file's location with the `where` command.

```
where steam.exe
```

Now you'd need to get the output of that command into a variable.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('where steam.exe') do set filelocation=%a
```

Now, due to one of the many, many quirks in BATCH the above `for` command will work as-is in a command window, but will need to be slightly modified in order to work in a BATCH file.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('where steam.exe') do set filelocation=%%a
```

Note there are two `%` characters preceding the letter `a`

If steam.exe is not on the system's PATH variable then you'll need to query the registry for Steam's installation directory. To do that you'll need to use the `reg` command and query somewhere under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

p.s. Sorry, I can't give you a more complete answer right now since I don't have a Windows machine at the moment

Comment: Unfortunately there is no path environment variable to it.

Comment: You always can search file by "dir /s C:\AcroRd32.exe" it will gives to you all AcroRd32.exe on disk C.

Comment: But then you have to do searches across all drives.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after Steam in particular, you can't rely on it being in the user PATH, and you probably don't want to search the whole drive for it. (You might find the wrong executable anyway.)

You're better off querying the registry for their Steam installation.

```
@echo off
rem this is quick and dirty
reg query HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam /v SteamExe>nul
if errorlevel 1 echo Steam not found for current user & goto :eof
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam /v SteamExe') do set steampath=%%a
steampath=%steampath:~26%
echo %steampath%
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with both 32 and 64 versions of Windows.

```
@echo off
(for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam" /v UninstallString`) do set SteamPath32=%%c)>nul 2>&1
(for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam" /v UninstallString`) do set SteamPath64=%%c)>nul 2>&1
set SteamPath=%SteamPath64%%SteamPath32%
set SteamPath=%SteamPath:\uninstall.exe=%
echo %SteamPath%
pause>nul
```